# can i use string.join in a generic list

Tags: c#

Is there a way to take generic list and join a certain property into a comma-separated value?

```
public class Color
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name{get; set;}
}

List<Color> list = new List<Color>();
Color c1 = new Color() { Id = 1, Name = "red" }
Color c2 = new Color() { Id = 2, Name = "blue" }
```

Can I do something like

```
list.Join(
```

to get

```
"red, blue";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot. This method is defined as `string.Join(String, String[])`. There is a way to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
string.Join(",", list.Select(c=>c.Name).ToArray());
```

Comment: The method has defenition string.Join(string,IEnumerable<T>) as well. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

This extension `Join` stands for LINQ `Join`.

```
List<Color> list = new List<Color>();
list.Join(...)
```

If you want to concatenate a collection in a string, you need to use `String.Join`.
The following will result in the desired `"red, blue"` string:

```
String.Join(", ", list.Select(x => x.Name));
```

Comment: You needed the ToString() override :)

Comment: @mrtig Yeah, I was in hurry. You deserve the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.Join for generics. But to get what you want you have to make some modifications to your code, otherwise you'll get something like this as result:

```
Namespace.Color, Namespace.Color
```

Option A as mrtig suggested:

```
String.Join(",", list.Select(x=>x.Name))
```

Option B, extend your class with ToString:

```
public class Color
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name{get; set;}
  public string ToString(){
    return this.Name;
  }
}
```

Now you can use just:

```
String.Join(",",list) //where list is IEnumerable<Color>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, as of .NET 4 [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) has an overload for [`String.Join(string, IEnumerable<string>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx). You can even avoid calling `ToString` by using the [`String.Join(string, IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) overload.

So these are both valid:

```
String.Join(",", new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });
String.Join(",", new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" });
```